# Salesforce Inbound Sms integration

Tags: salesforce, sms, messaging, apex, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to trigger an apex class on every inbound text message received for messaging session in omni channel tab. But I am not able to find any object that can be used to attach a trigger on it. Have searched online as well, but in most of the guides they use third party services like twilio, Mercury etc. Can someone help me to implement this without any third-party service?

Answer (score 0):

You should try agent work or pending service routing objects I think

Comment: Hey I did try but no luck